# SharePoint 2013 JSLink Not working on LinkTitle Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I applied JSlink for LinkTitle Column I am not able to see the JS is loading at all. But all for other Columns and my custom columns too I can apply.

Is their any difference over here..Please help me asap..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to customize field rendering in List View (SharePoint 2013)

Below is demonstrated how to customize `LinkTitle` column rendering

1) Create template

```
(function () {


   function titleRenderer(ctx) {
       var item = ctx.CurrentItem;
       return '<img src="/SiteAssets/' +  item.Title + '.png" />';  
    }



    function registerRenderer()
    {
      var context = {};
      context.Templates = {};
      context.Templates.Fields = {
        "LinkTitle": {
            "View": titleRenderer
        }
      };

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(context);
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

where we override `LinkTitle` field rendering

2) Upload template file into, for example, `Site Assets` library

3) Specify JS Link property for List View web part
Example: `~site/SiteAssets/Phones.js`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This kind of answer the question, but you need to modify all the List Views to apply it.

I have been able to change the LinkTitle site column jslink, and the result is there:

```
<d:JSLink>~sitecollection/umaAssets/project-card/assets/jslink/task-title.js</d:JSLink>
```

but when I create a list using this column, the list column has a jslink of null:

```
<d:JSLink m:null="true"/>
```

There seems to be no correlation between the two.